# Graphviz not generating gif

Tags: java, graphviz

I have installed graphviz and trying to generate gif using java. Nothing is written to gif file. But if create a svg it works.

Could someone let me know how to do this ?

Regards

Comment: How did you install graphviz?

Comment: Yes i have install graphviz.. I am able to generate svg files but not gif or png

Comment: No, not *have you...* - I asked *how* you installed it - compiled from src? From a package? Via a repository?

Comment: I followed this link and did make install http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/graphviz.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed on the GraphViz Gitlab site: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1450

You need to install GraphViz-GD, the GraphViz plugin for renderers based on GD: `yum install graphviz-gd`
We are using graphviz-gd-2.40.1-40.el8.x86_64.rpm on CentOs 8 without problems (so far...). You can find different versions of the RPM for example here:
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=graphviz-gd

Answer (score 0):

If you type `dot -Tx` at the command line, you should get a message something like:

```
Format: "x" not recognized. Use one of: bmp canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot emf 
emfplus eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg metafile pdf pic 
plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tif tiff tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp xdot
```

If `gif` is not on the list in your case, you could try outputting to another bitmap format (e.g. `png` or `jpg`) and then using another program to convert to `.gif`.

Comment: I got the following. Now I am converting svg to png using Batik API        

Format: "x" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg tk vml xdot

Comment: No bitmap formats are shown in the list output by `dot`, which shows that your version of GraphViz has not been compiled with any bitmap formats included. You will have to re-compile GraphViz with the bitmap formats. Possibly you do not have some of the libraries on which the bitmap formats depend, e.g. libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1, libpng-1.6.2

Comment: I have install libpng and also used the following command to reinstall graphviz but still png donot appear in my list. ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pnglibdir=/usr/local/lib/ --with-pngincludedir=//usr/local/include/libpng16/ --disable-static && make
make install

Comment: In that case, I suggest: 1) you could try `which dot` to confirm that the version of `dot` you are using is the one that you have just installed (if it is not, you might need to adjust your PATH so that you are using that version), or 2) try to find a pre-built package for your Linux that will install GraphViz without the need for compilation, or 3) if you have to compile GraphViz from source, you could try asking another question - something like "I have installed GraphViz from source but the bitmap formats are missing" and describe exactly how you built and installed it.

Comment: graphviz-2.30.1]$ which dot
/usr/bin/dot  I think it is taking the wrong one. any clue ?

Comment: If you check the date on `/usr/bin/dot` that will tell you for sure if it is the one that you just installed or if it is another one. If it is another one, you could do one of: 1) look at the install script to see where it is putting the new version of `dot` then ensure that directory is on your PATH before `/usr/bin`, 2) tell the install script to install the new GraphViz programs to `/usr/bin`, or 3) when you've found where the new programs are located, put links to those programs in `/usr/bin` to replace the existing programs.

Comment: Its the latest one -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24057 May  7 13:53 /usr/bin/dot